# How to open file in java and parse each line

Tags: java, regex, parsing, file-io

I have a text file containing data like this:

> sender id: 1/sequence number: 0/depth: 600/sending time: 13/05/2018
>   11:17:17 ص/data: Hello I am AUV: 1 this is aggregation # 0 from my
>   sideEnd-End Delay:0.357072263241232 sender id: 0/sequence number:
>   0/depth: 700/sending time: 13/05/2018 11:17:17 ص/data: Hello I am AUV:
>   0 this is aggregation # 0 from my sideEnd-End Delay:0.293693984840975
>   sender id: 2/sequence number: 0/depth: 500/sending time: 13/05/2018
>   11:17:17 ص/data: Hello I am AUV: 2 this is aggregation # 0 from my
>   sideEnd-End Delay:0.421466419584594 sender id: 3/sequence number:
>   0/depth: 400/sending time: 13/05/2018 11:17:17 ص/data: Hello I am AUV:
>   3 this is aggregation # 0 from my sideEnd-End Delay:0.486473186901286
>   sender id: 3/sequence number: 1/depth: 400/sending time: 13/05/2018
>   11:17:18 ص/data: Hello I am AUV: 3 this is aggregation # 1 from my
>   sideEnd-End Delay:0.486473186901286 sender id: 1/sequence number:
>   0/depth: 600/sending time: 13/05/2018 11:17:21 ص/data: Hello I am AUV:
>   1 this is aggregation # 0 from my sideEnd-End Delay:0.32221205728025
>   sender id: 0/sequence number: 0/depth: 700/sending time: 13/05/2018
>   11:17:21 ص/data: Hello I am AUV: 0 this is aggregation # 0 from my
>   sideEnd-End Delay:0.267329486404354

Each line ends with the end-end delay, for example line#1:

> sender id: 1/sequence number: 0/depth: 600/sending time: 13/05/2018
>   11:17:17 ص/data: Hello I am AUV: 1 this is aggregation # 0 from my
>   sideEnd-End Delay:0.357072263241232

I need to divide this file into others files where each file corresponding to a specific sender id.

Each file will contain the end-end delay values for each sender id only such as 0.357072263241232.

I have 4 senders so 4 files will be generated ...

Any help or any hint please ?

I don't have the experience with regex!

Comment: Question: Are you certain that each line does not already end in a newline or carriage return?

Comment: each line end by a new line and at the end of each line there is a double value ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `sender\sid:\s(\d+).*?End-End\sDelay:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kXgfHi/2/)

Group 1 will have the sender id

Group 2 will have the end - end delay value

Comment: How to use it with open file method and store the result in the correct file with append option?

Comment: I'm afraid, I'll not be able to help you much with the exact Java code. This [link](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/how-to-read-and-write-text-file-in-java#highlighter_835442) could be a starting point for you